# Trying to use desktop output as a microphone input in python speech recognition

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition

I have tried to create a program that recognizes live audio and if there is any key phrases in that audio, the program does x.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
   print(f'{index}, {name}')

rc = sr.Recognizer()


while True:
    try:
        with sr.Microphone(device_index = 0) as source:
            rc.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = .2)
            audio = rc.listen(source)

            text = rc.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text.lower()
            print(text)
            if badword in text:
                 print("don't say that!")
    except:
        continue
```

When using any device other than an actual microphone for device_index, the program runs with no error messages and prints nothing. I have tried every listed output that I know is available(plugged in).

Answer (score 0):

In the taskbar, right-click the sound icon -> sounds, then go to the recording tab. Right click and activate, show disabled devices. Find in the list the "steromixer" right click that and press activate. Then find out what device index it has and use that as device index when you set your mic.

In my case in my list when I have printed the devices out there were multiple stereomixers. I'll just have tried on out and if that one has not worked, I have just tried another one.